# Convert date received as /Date(1463698800000+0100)/ to java Date Object using jackson

Tags: json, date, jackson, resttemplate

Convert date received as /Date(1463698800000+0100)/ to java Date Object using jackson. I am getting this in a rest response. Using spring restTemplate and jackson to convert response to Java Object. Is it possible to give a format like `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", locale = "en-us", timezone = "IST")`

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag if you are looking for JAVA solutions?

Comment: @mplungjan while checking on google somebody said it's a javascipt format. removed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Epoch reference

The string `1463698800000+0100` likely represents a count of milliseconds from an [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)). Unfortunately we do not know which of the [couple dozen epoch reference points commonly used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) are in play here.

## Offset

The `+0100` is likely short for `+01:00` meaning an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of one hour and zero minutes (and implied zero seconds). This really complicates matters, as we do not know if we were meant to adjust by an hour before or after making our count from the epoch reference.

## Impossible problem

So, you have a mess here, an impossible problem. You could guess, on both points (epoch, and offset), but it would be only a guess. Personally, I would refuse this programming assignment as impossible to get right with certainty.

If you had a greater context, with some example data with known inputs and outputs, you may be able to experiment to verify your guesses. But we do not have that information at hand in this Question.

## ISO 8601

Ideally, you would track down the publisher of this data and educate them about the proper way to communicate date-time values as text: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Example: `2020-01-23T01:23:45.123Z`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-01-23T01:23:45.123Z" ) ;
String output = instant.toString() ;  // 2020-01-23T01:23:45.123Z
```